Wrong page gets loaded occasionally
These are the routes of my app that are implied in the problem :
-login
-forgottenpassword
|->[temporary_link]
When the user forgets his password, he gos from /login to /forgottenpassword : he then submits his email adress and receives an email with a link getting him to forgottenpassword/temporarylink, where he should write his new password both.
When he clicks this link however, he is not routed to the right page but to the /login page.
All the other pages work fine.
My code is visible on github :
https://github.com/dimitrilazarevic/Le_petit_blog_des_petits_potins/tree/master/src/routes
The only way I found to get around this bug is, each time I run the server, I have to rename the forgottenpassword folder to something else and then give it back its original name. When I do this, i get to the right page and it works, and if I do the same steps repeatedly (forgotten password/email/link) it continues working. But I have no clue why this bug happens or how to get rid of it permanently. Do you guys happen to know what could happen ?
If anything is unclear I will be glad to answer.
Thanks for your help !

I need to add something : the error occured with brave browser. I then tried with chrome or firefox and it worked just fine... Maybe not a problem with svelteKit ?
